# Proving that $\int \frac{dx}{(1-x^2)}$ equals the inverse hyperbolic tangent of $x$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I prove the following fact

$$\int\limits \dfrac{dx}{(1-x^2)}=\tanh^{-1}x$$

I show, by integrating by substitution, that the integral equals

$$- \dfrac{\ln(1-x^2)}{2x}.$$

Setting $x=\tanh z$, we get $$-\dfrac{\ln\operatorname{sech} z}{\tanh z}.$$

Then, since $z=\tanh^{-1}x$, the above equation yields

$$-\dfrac{\ln(1-x^2)}{2x}.$$

Is this sufficient to prove the first equation?

Comment: Your second and fourth equations are the same, so I don't see the point of going via the third. Furthermore, I'm fairly sure that you got the integral wrong (please explain how you got it!). Would it not be simpler to differentiate the inverse hyperbolic tangent?

Comment: Yes, but I want to see how that works, for argument's sake.

Comment: Anyway, thanks for your time

Comment: I mean, I see two possible attacks here. A natural one (that you started on), is to find the indefinite integral, and then prove (by some manipulations) that the result is the inverse $\tanh$. Another natural one is to verify the correctness of the claim by differentiating.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your integration is **incorrect**; the derivative of $-\frac{\ln(1-x^{2})}{2x}$ is $$-\frac{\frac{2x}{1-x^{2}}-2\ln(1-x^{2})}{4x^{2}}$$
The correct way to proceed is by partial fractions; notice the following:
$$\frac{1}{1-x^{2}}=\frac{1}{(1-x)(1+x)}=\frac{1}{2(1-x)}+\frac{1}{2(1+x)}$$
And so, integrating this, we get$$\int\frac{1}{1-x^{2}}dx=\int\frac{1}{2(1-x)}+\int\frac{1}{2(1+x)}=\frac{1}{2}\left(-\ln(1-x)+\ln(1+x)\right)=\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)$$
Which is another expression for $\tanh^{-1}(x)$ - are you familiar with this?

As an aside, I think I can see where your incorrect expression has come from, and it is important to see that it is wrong. When integrating by substitution, you appear to know that we must compute the derivative of our substitution - in this case, the derivative $1-x^{2}$ is $-2x$. However, we **cannot** bring this outside of the integral.

Answer (score 2):

By integrating by method of partial fractions, you will see that the result is not correct. I think you can use the definition of $\tanh x=\frac{e^{x}-e^{-x}}{e^{x}+e^{-x}}=1-\frac{2e^{-x}}{e^{x}+e^{-x}}=y$ instead. Do the right integration first, and then find $y$ with respect to $x$. Note that $|x|<1$.

Comment: Well said! $\large \langle + \rangle$